# Inherit model with hierarchy

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

I use c# (but no matter) and have the following model:

```
public abstract class SuspensionRequestCreatedBaseDto
{
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public string DeviceIMEI { get; set; }
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }
}

public class SuspensionRequestCreatedExpirationTimeDto : SuspensionRequestCreatedBaseDto
{
    public DateTime? LastActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime ApprovePlannedDateTime { get; set; }
}

public class SuspensionRequestCreatedReachDataLimitDto : SuspensionRequestCreatedBaseDto
{
    public int DataUsedMb { get; set; }
}
```

I use these classes for my Services libraries, so, there are common DTO classes

But for one UI project I need to have the following logic:

```
public abstract class SuspensionRequestCreatedBaseDto
{
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public string DeviceIMEI { get; set; }
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }

    public virtual string PrepareEmailPart(string body)
    {
        // logic 1 (base logic)
    }
}

public class SuspensionRequestCreatedExpirationTimeDto : SuspensionRequestCreatedBaseDto
{
    public DateTime? LastActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime ApprovePlannedDateTime { get; set; }

    public override string PrepareEmailPart(string body)
    {
        // logic 2
    }
}

public class SuspensionRequestCreatedReachDataLimitDto : SuspensionRequestCreatedBaseDto
{
    public int DataUsedMb { get; set; }

    public override string PrepareEmailPart(string body)
    {
        // logic 3
    }
}
```

then just call `request.PrepareEmailPart(...)` without checking type of Dto class. But I can't add such specific things (UI things) to Core library, which I use for Services.

I try to implement it like:

```
public class SuspensionRequestCreatedBaseModel
{
    public virtual SuspensionRequestCreatedBaseDto SuspensionRequest { get; set; }

    public virtual string PrepareEmailPart(string body)
    {
         // base logic
    }
}

public class SuspensionRequestCreatedExpirationTimeModel : SuspensionRequestCreatedBaseModel
{
    public override SuspensionRequestCreatedExpirationTimeDto SuspensionRequest {get; set;}

    public override string PrepareEmailPart(string body)
    {
        // logic 2
    }
}
```

but I get

> 'SuspensionRequestCreatedExpirationTimeModel.SuspensionRequest':
> type must be 'SuspensionRequestCreatedBaseDto' to match overridden
> member
> 'SuspensionRequestCreatedBaseModel.SuspensionRequest'

How to implement it correctly, without `case` antipattern and without mixing unnecessary UI things to Core?

Comment: Bit confused as to why `SuspensionRequestCreatedBaseModel` contains an instance of `SuspensionRequestCreatedBaseDto` rather than being mapped to it eg with AutoMapper? Also confused why the DTO classes have implementations of `PrepareEmailPart`, shouldn’t that be something the model class does? Haven’t used the DTO pattern for a while (not a fan) but as I recall the DTO classes are just ‘dumb classes’. I’m sure I’m just missing something.

Comment: @stuartd I just shown on Dto classes which model I want to have. Inherited properties with inherited logic. Of course, DTO classes should not have logic. I have pure DTO classes, but I how to have classes with logic? Also, don't understood, how to map using Automapper rather than property type? Which type of property should be for SuspensionRequestCreatedXXXModel  ?